# Application Insights Alert (Response Time) triggering when all my requests are below the limit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour in production where my Insights Alert for response time (> than 3 secs in the last 5 minutes) is triggering all the time but if I look into the logged requests most of them are lower than my threshold.

In the first picture you can see that there is a time in the last 24 hours that my average response time is greater than a minute, but in the second picture we can see that for the same time there is no request with more than 30 sec. So, how the average can be > than 1 minute?

We are using Azure Mobile Apps, SignalR (but the SignalR requests are being ignored using a filter) and our Insights version is 2.6.4.

**Images**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Alert for response time (> than 3 secs in the last 5 minutes) is triggering all the time - From the first picture, it shows average response time is 11sec which is good enough to trigger the >3sec trigger - right?

Comment: Yes but if you see the second picture you can see that there is no delay with a big response enought to make the average 11 seconds.

Comment: A UI bug? can you use analytics query to find out the actual value of response timer?

Comment: I used the analytics and no requests that could result in a 1.5 minute average.

Comment: The Overview UI (the 1st picture) was recently changed.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview-dashboard   Can you re-check this ? If there is discrepancy in the data in analytics and UI then its likely UI bug. Please try this again( if you havn't already!) and let me know

Comment: It's not the overview that looks wrong, the alerts are also being triggered. I think that they are not ignoring the requests I'm ignoring using the telemetry filter, like SignalR requests.

Comment: Alright. Now I see what's the issue. You have a TelemetryProcessor which filters out SignalRequests (which had high response times).  The alerting is based on the response *before* your processor filters out. If you intent to do alert based on the response duration *after* the filters, then i'd suggest to use log based alert. With a query like "requests 
| where timestamp >= ago(15m)
| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(duration) by bin(timestamp,1m)"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-alerts-unified-log#metric-measurement-alert-rules  Docs about setting up alerts based on logs.